# Can't create projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am facing an issue with Visual Studio 2015. When I click on new project/add new file, I get an error message. I get this error even for clicking few menu items.

[image: Error when click on new project]

> Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.

I even get few more errors like:

[image: Another error]

> The 'XamlDesignerPackage' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\MY PC\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
>
> Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue.

[image: Few settings getting failed]

I have tried repair and reinstall(uninstall and install again) both didn't have any effect.

These are the errors found in ActivityLog.xml

```
<entry>
<record>392</record>
<time>2018/02/09 02:11:35.915</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Extension Manager</source>
<description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\10\DESKTOP SDK\...</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\</path>
```

```
<entry>
<record>400</record>
<time>2018/02/09 02:11:47.980</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspaces.Contracts, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. Could not find or load a type. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131522)</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\HEXW0BB4.KCG\TMLanguage.dll</path>
```

```
<entry>
<record>420</record>
<time>2018/02/09 02:12:00.074</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>SetSite failed for package [ServiceProviderPackage]Source: &apos;GitHub.VisualStudio&apos; Description: Could not load type &apos;GitHub.Services.IUIProvider&apos; from assembly &apos;GitHub.Exports, Version=2.4.2.1331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bc1bd09f2901c82e&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type &apos;GitHub.Services.IUIProvider&apos; from assembly &apos;GitHub.Exports, Version=2.4.2.1331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bc1bd09f2901c82e&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at GitHub.VisualStudio.ServiceProviderPackage.InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress`1 progress)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass16_0.&lt;&lt;Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize&gt;b__1&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()</description>
<guid>{D5CE1488-DEDE-426D-9E5B-BFCCFBE33E53}</guid>
<hr>80131522</hr>
<errorinfo></errorinfo>
```

And there are few more.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: If you do a Google search on the first error you'll find a lot of suggestions to run "devenv /resetuserdata" and then reboot. If that doesn't solve the problem you may want to start going through the results of the search trying different things. https://www.bing.com/search?q=set+property+deferrablecontent+threw+an+exception

Comment: devenv /resetuserdata removed all my data but didn't solve the issue.